# Menu bar links CSS color not changing

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style the links in my navbar by changing the font color to white, but the color remains unchanged. I've tried targeting different selectors: `.navbar`, `.ul` and `.li` but nothing works. What am I doing wrong? I've also tried changing it to other colors besides white, without success.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background-image: url("stock.jpg");
}
.navbar{
    background-color: black;
}
.navbar .li {
    color: white!important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar .li .a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title></title>
</head>  

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="">STEEPLE BREWERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Reservations</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Giftcards</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Team</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You never changed the color of the anchors: `.navbar a { color: white; }`. Also you should use the semantic tags for multiple reasons (accessability with screen readers) such as `<nav>` instead of `div class="navbar">`

Comment: I recommend reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors or a general CSS tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) `li` and `a` elements are *no*  classes, therefore you must not write a dot before them in your CSS selectors:

2.) The color has to be defined for the link, i.e. the `a` tag, not for the `li` (the color for that will be overwritten by the link color, even by the default color, if you don't define one)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url("stock.jpg");
}

.navbar {
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="">STEEPLE BREWERY</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Reservations</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Locations</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Giftcards</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Team</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```